# css float doesn't resize to fit new content

Tags: css

I have a form I'm floating. When there is an error, via jquery, I'm adding some content to a p within the form. However, the form doesn't vertically resize to fit the new content. Is there something I have to do to get a floated element to resize when the content within it changes?

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had a height set and just didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `height` or other css styling applied that would prevent it from vertically resizing?

Also, what browser(s) is it happening in?  It may be a browser bug.

If the

is floated, too, then depending on the styling (position: absolute), its dimensions may not be considered to be "in" the form.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a height set on the content?  When float is on, the default is to fix height to line height. It is possible that your width on the form is set too low, and the text is trailing off through the block element containing your form  Try messing with the line-height property and see what you get.  Also, position absolute will mess with you (as Richard mentions below)

Also, consider min-height.  This won't work in IE6, but you can substitute with a height in IE6 which acts like min-height in certain circumstances.

Post you code so I can be more specific.